# ADF: Calling a method through a managed beans in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jspx

I am running into issues with passing parameters to managed beans in JSP within Oracle ADF. Here is an example JSP test page I am trying to pass parameters to a test method in a POJO:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"/>
  <f:view>
    <af:document title="Automated Scheduling Tool > Customer Portal > Packages"
                 id="d1">
      <af:messages id="m1"/>
      <af:form id="f1">
        <center>
          <br/><br/><br/>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="45" width="800">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" class="darkBackground">
                <span class="largeTitle">AUTOMATED SCHEDULING TOOL</span>                 
                <br/>                 
                <span class="mediumTitle">CUSTOMER PORTAL</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <af:outputText value="#{pageFlowScope.customerFacadeBean.test['test1', 'test2']}" id="ot1" />
            </tr>
          </table>
        </center>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>

public class CustomerFacade {
    private final PackageMapper mapper;
    private List<Package> packages;

    public CustomerFacade() {
        mapper = new PackageMapper();
        packages = mapper.findAllPackages();
    }

    public List<Package> getPackages() {
        return packages;
    }


    public String test(String testString1, String testString2){
        System.out.println(testString1 + testString2);
        return "Success!";
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can pass parameters to the POJO via a managed bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#{pageFlowScope.customerFacadeBean.test['test1', 'test2']}
```

This is not a legal Unified Expression Language expression. You could probably do something like this:

```
#{pageFlowScope.customerFacadeBean.test['test1']['test2']}
```

...where `test` resolved to a map of maps:

```
  public Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> getTest() {
    return new HashMap<Object, Map<Object, Object>>() {
      @Override
      public Map<Object, Object> get(final Object test1) {
        return new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
          @Override
          public Object get(Object test2) {
            return getSomething(test1, test2);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }

  private Object getSomething(Object test1, Object test2) {
    //TODO
  }
```

Obviously, this is really ugly.

You could try [implementing a custom function](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaiq) in the form `#{stuff:callTest(pageFlowScope.customerFacadeBean, 'test1', 'test2')}`.

Servers implementing [JSP 2.1 Maintenance Release 2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr245/245-MR2_2.html) should support expressions of the form `#{mybean.something(param)}` ([read this for more info](http://www.mojavelinux.com/blog/archives/2009/08/why_you_didnt_know_the_unified_el_is_being_updated/)). Some frameworks may already support this syntax - it's worth checking the doc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat elegant alternative solution similar to the above: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Parameters_In_EL_Functions